# SharePoint 2013 Word Automation Services on demand error code 10

Tags: word-automation

I have been stuck on this issue for couple of days. In my development environment which is a standalone SharePoint enterprise, the following code works flawlessly:

```
SyncConverter syncConv = new SyncConverter(“Word Automation Services”); 
syncConv.Settings.OutputFormat = SaveFormat.PDF;
ConversionItemInfo convInfo = syncConv.Convert(inStream, outStream);
```

In the staging environment, I get the following as soon as it reaches the "Convert".

> ErrorCode:10,  ErrorMessage:The file could not be converted due to an
>   intermittent error in the system. Please resubmit this file for
>   conversion. If the file fails again with this error message, contact
>   your system administrator.

I am looking online for solution for days but no luck.

Help! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was Single Server used for SQL, SharePoint and **Domain Controller**. It seems that if Domain controller in on the same server, security restricts from running\invoking most of the services even if the user has farm admin account.

For me User profile synchronization was stuck in "Starting" state and Word Automation was throwing the exception mentioned above. Once I removed the Domain Controller as a separate server, all these problems got resolved.

Comment: So, does this mean, your development server didn't have domain controller on the server but your staging had? Very interesting finding indeed!